# Не работает перегруженный operator[]

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Это часть заголовочного файла:

```
    public ref class Matrix
    {
    private:
      array<array<double>^>^ M;
      int lines, columns;
    public:
      Matrix(const int l, const int c);
      Matrix(const Matrix% m);
      Matrix(const Matrix% m, const int i);
      array<double>^ operator[](const int i){return M[i];}
      double Determinant();
      double Gauss(array<double>^ r);
  };
```

Это реализация конструктора копирования:

```
ClassMatrix::Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix% m)
{
  lines = m.lines;
  columns = m.columns;
  M = gcnew array<array<double>^ >(lines);
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
  {
    M[i] = gcnew array<double>(columns);
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
      M[i][j] = m[i][j];
  }
}
```

**m[i][j]** - ошибка: "выражение должно содержать тип указателя на объект или дескриптора массива". Что я сделал неверно?

Comment: Не уверен как надо работать с `^`, но попробуйте переписать оператор `[]` так  `array<double>& operator[](const int i){return (*M)[i];}`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Нет, не проходят ни &, ни %

Comment: Ха, как странно работает компилятор. Выяснилось, что он обнаруживает ошибку в реализации (как в примере). Однако, при исполнении в программе оператор работает как положено. Требую пояснений!!!